# Performance with bash loop when renaming files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Sometimes I need to rename some amount of files, such as add a prefix or remove something.
At first I wrote a python script. It works well, and I want a shell version. Therefore I wrote something like that:

$1 - which directory to list, 
$2 - what pattern will be replacement, 
$3 - replacement.

```
echo "usage: dir pattern replacement"
for fname in `ls $1`
do
  newName=$(echo $fname | sed "s/^$2/$3/")
  echo 'mv' "$1/$fname" "$1/$newName&&"
  mv "$1/$fname" "$1/$newName"
done
```

It works but very slowly, probably because it needs to create a process (here `sed` and `mv`) and destroy it and create same process again just to have a different argument. Is that true? If so, how to avoid it, how can I get a faster version?

I thought to offer all processed files a name (using `sed` to process them at once), but it still needs `mv` in the loop.

Please tell me, how you guys do it? Thanks. If you find my question hard to understand please be patient, my English is not very good, sorry.

--- update ---

I am sorry for my description. My core question is: "IF we should use some command in loop, will that lower performance?" Because in `for i in {1..100000}; do ls 1>/dev/null; done` creating and destroying a process will take most of the time. So what I want is "Is there any way to reduce that cost?".

Thanks to kev and S.R.I for giving me a `rename` solution to rename files.

Comment: have you tried the `rename` command?

Comment: @kev I think whatever command i using it still in loop so the bad performance will never change. It that right?

Comment: @Pikaurd, have a look at my answer. `rename` is an ELF executable and it doesn't have to execute in a loop via shell programming

Comment: @kev @S.R.I I have never used `rename` before and after test I noticed macosx haven't that command. But thanks to giving me a solution.

Comment: Is it actually a regex you wish to replace, or is it a shell glob?

Comment: @feg OK, I'll ask another question with another style.

Comment: Python or Perl will give you better performance because they invoke the system calls direct from the interpreter, whereas the shell script has to run programs (`fork()` + `exec()` + `wait()`) to do the same job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call an external binary (`ls`, `sed`, `mv`), bash has to fork itself to exec the command and that takes a big performance hit.

You can do everything you want to do in pure bash 4.X and only need to call `mv`

```
pat_rename(){ 
  if [[ ! -d "$1" ]]; then
    echo "Error: '$1' is not a valid directory"
    return
  fi
  shopt -s globstar
  cd "$1"
  for file in **; do
    echo "mv $file ${file//$2/$3}"
  done
}
```

Comment: So… as long as we need enteral binary, there will not change. Right?

Comment: "bash has to fork itself to create a subshell" -- not quite: it only forks() to execve() the command ;) But yes, it is quite a performance hit in any case.

Comment: @fge technically between the time it fork()'s and execve()'s, which is probably just a line of code to check if the fork failed, it's subshell =).  In any case, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest first. What's wrong with `rename`?

```
mkdir tstbin
for i in `seq 1 20`
do
   touch tstbin/filename$i.txt
done
rename .txt .html tstbin/*.txt
```

Or are you using an older *nix machine?

Comment: Numerous things are wrong with rename. It's not POSIX (so may be unavailable), it doesn't replace patterns anywhere (just extensions), and maybe more things.

Comment: @Jens, Yeah, you're right. I'm aware that `rename` may not be available in all bash environments. That was why I asked the question I did. The OP did not specify their OS environment until much later.

Comment: @Jens, I use rename regularly, but hardly ever to rename extensions, so I believe you got that wrong. Your point still stands, though.

Comment: @Pianosaurus Thanks for the correction. Indeed, rename replaces the *first* occurrence of the pattern. This is problematic in cases where the pattern may occur prior to the part you actually want replaced.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid re-executing sed on each file, you could instead setup two name streams, one original, and one transformed, then sip from the ends:

```
exec 3< <(ls)
exec 4< <(ls | sed 's/from/to/')

IFS=`echo`
while read -u3 orig && read -u4 to; do
    mv "${orig}" "${to}";
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store all of file names into a file or string, and use awk and sed do it once instead of one by one.